# maya python __file__ returns a mixture of forward and backslashes

Tags: python, windows, maya

I need to return the **file** location of a module within maya. I am using a simple print of the **file**

I noticed that the return value has a mixture of both forward and backslashes, which is a bit of a pain when it comes to splitting / stripping. Does anyone know if this is a python / maya / windows things , and expected ?

```
def getScriptLocation():
    localPath = (__file__)
    print (localPath)
    return localPath
```

C:/Users/blamb/Documents/maya/scripts\modelnom\layoutTools\pathPlot\stitchUpVars.py

Comment: python's `pathlib` should make the handling of mixed slashes easy, e.g. `print(Path(__file__))`

Comment: If you are on Windows, try to use `.replace("\\", "/")` after `os.path` operations. That way you'll make path handling platform-independent. These mixed slashes come from `os.path` utils that tend to return backslashes on windows and some path parts that come from the environment (that could have forward slashes).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Python 3.4+, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module acts as a wrapper and will return a normalized path for your specific os. If you need backwards compatibility [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) is the way to go.